# Dataset rearrangement

Tags: dataset, associations

I have a datatset , and I want to sort the elements in the second column so that the elements in the other columns change accordingly.

```
dataset= {<|index -> 1, name -> N, x-> 1, y -> 1.5, z -> 1.7|>, 
          <|index -> 2, name -> C, x-> 2, z -> 2.7|>, 
          <|index -> 3, name -> H, x-> 3, y -> 3.5, z -> 3.7|>,...}
```

e.g. i want change name element to HCN instead of NCH. when i use `dataset[All, "name"] = HCN` just elements in name column were changed but their values in rest XYZ column did not change.

Comment: `dataset[[{3,2,1}]]`? It doesn't look like there's a natural sort to be taken advantage of there, but you can just re-pick the dataset manually (with `Part` (`[[...]]`)) since there's only 3 members.

Answer (score 2):

```
myordering = AssociationThread[{H, C, N}, Range[3]];

SortBy[myordering @ #[name] &] @ dataset
```

> ```
>  {<|index -> 3, name -> H, x -> 3, y -> 3.5, z -> 3.7|>, 
>   <|index -> 2, name -> C, x -> 2, z -> 2.7|>, 
>   <|index -> 1, name -> N, x -> 1, y -> 1.5, z -> 1.7|>}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[777]
dataset2 = RandomChoice[dataset, 15];

Row[Column /@ {dataset2, SortBy[myordering @ #[name]&] @ dataset2}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]